# Nashorn - How to get a JS Array in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, nashorn

I have this JS function:

```
function newJSArray() {return []}
```

That I am trying to return in Java using the following method:

```
public static NativeArray newArray() throws Exception {
    return (NativeArray)invocable.invokeFunction("newJSArray");
}
```

But it's throwing an exception when I try to invoke this function:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ....JavaScript.newArray()Ljdk/nashorn/api/scripting/JSObject;
    at ....
```

I want to be given a JS array specifically so I can call jsArr1.concat(jsArr2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all API methods return JavaScript objects as instances of jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.JSObject. You can access members of that JS array by JSObject.getSlot method.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the object returned was a JSObject.